# Custom styling for ASP textboxes

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I currently have two textboxes (`asp:TextBox`) in close proximity to each other. They currently look like this:

[image]

I'm attempting to get rid of that shadow effect that is applied to the top and left edges of the textboxes, in order that I can apply some custom styling. However, `box-shadow` seems to have no effect and adding a `border` property adds to the existing shadow, rather than replacing it. Is it easier to replace the textbox styling entirely, or can I do something with the existing template?

My objective is a simpler textbox, like the title textbox on StackOverflow when asking a new question:

[image]

Edit: This is the current CSS applied:

[image]

And with `border-width` removed:

[image]

Note that `box-shadow` has no effect when applied or removed. The only visual difference is that the border is thicker, and still is biased towards the top and left sides of the object.

Comment: Use F12 and see which CSS rule is being applied?

Comment: Please use the web developer tools available in browsers to see the CSS rules applied to the textboxes. Paste the CSS too.

Comment: Remove the border-radius, and leave the border-width as is. How does that look?

Comment: @IrishChieftain All this does is make my boxes square. The rounded corners were a deliberate move on my part.

Comment: The sample you wanted to emulate has square corners? I'll post a possible answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
.loginInputBox
{
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    box-shadow: none;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was successful. Is there still a specific need for the Mozilla variant, now that FF v57 is here? Or is it just generally good practice to include the two separate radius/shadow properties?

Comment: I would include them for the slightly older versions as many people are still using them.